# two date comparisn gives Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where dates are stored in as text because this field can also store something else.

I need extract the rows with a date in that field and this date has to be within now + 2 months.

My query is:

```
;WITH sel AS (SELECT t1.ItemUserID, t3.Omschrijving AS Hoofditem, 
              t4.Omschrijving AS Subitem, t2.Omschrijving AS SubItemonderdeel,
              CONVERT(DATE,t1.subitemwaarde) AS subitemwaarde,
              CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(month, 2, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101))) as now_plus_2
             FROM MainDataTable AS t1
             LEFT JOIN SubItemsOnderdelen AS t2 ON t1.SubItemonderdeel=t2.Code 
             LEFT JOIN HoofdItemOnderdelen AS t3 ON t1.Hoofditem = t3.Code
             LEFT JOIN ItemData AS t4 ON t1.subitem=t4.itemcode 
             WHERE t2.Omschrijving LIKE 'expires on' 
               and ISDATE(t1.SubItemWaarde) = 1)

SELECT * FROM sel AS t2
```

If I run this, I get a table with all the data, the last two columns are showing dates and are date columns.

When I add 
    WHERE t2.subitemwaarde< t2.now_plus_2
to the last SELECT statement, I get the error:

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

why? What am I doing wrong?

rg.
Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude the non-dates in the `JOIN` clause itself prior to filtering with WHERE

```
ON t1.SubItemonderdeel=t2.Code and ISDATE(t1.SubItemWaarde) = 1)
```

You should also consider adding a set of columns appropriate to their data type.

Answer (score 1):

`t2.subitemwaarde< t2.now_plus_2` compares a `String` with a `Date`. Convert `t2.subitemwaarde` to a Date before comparing to solve the problem:

```
CONVERT(DATE,t2.subitemwaarde) < t2.now_plus_2
```

This will cause errors if `t2.subitemwaarde` is not a date, so you may need to add the filter 
`ISDATE(t2.subitemwaarde) = 1`.

Comment: he said it also stores "something else"...don't you think he will facing exactly the same problems?

Comment: Not if the predicate AND ISDATE(t1.SubItemWaarde) = 1 is applied.

Comment: Agreed...I just didn't see that in your answer

Comment: It isn't, I thought it was in the original query, but looking closely I see now that t1.subitemwaarde is checked if it is a date but the comparison is for t2.subitemwaarde - so that also has to be checked...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I think you have to used below format. Because i don't know which date format you to convert.

```
select CONVERT(Datetime,'20/12/2012 12:12:00.000',103)
```

Comment: what happens if it's not a date?

Comment: if given format is date then its convert otherwise its implement other logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand which field you are comparing as a date, but try something like this:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN ISDATE(t2.SubItemWaarde) = 1) 
  THEN CONVERT(DATE, t2.subitemwaarde) < t2.now_plus_2
  ELSE 1=0
  END
```

Basically a case statement to check if the field is a date, and then the condition, else 1=0 which is always false so that row would be left out